# tmpfs partitions using a lot of space?

Tags: partition, centos7

I bought a centos 7 minimal server with 512Gb x 2 NVMe SSDs in software raid 1
When I enter df -h command I get:

```
[root@CentOS-72-64-minimal ~]# df -h
Filesystem  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md2  438G  935M  415G  1% /
devtmpfs  32G  0  32G  0% /dev
tmpfs  32G  0  32G  0% /dev/shm
tmpfs  32G  33M  32G  1% /run
tmpfs  32G  0  32G  0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md1  488M  121M  342M  26% /boot
tmpfs  6.3G  0  6.3G  0% /run/user/0
```

/etc/tempfs

```
proc /proc proc defaults 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts gid=5,mode=620 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs defaults 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs defaults 0 0
/dev/md/0 none swap sw 0 0
/dev/md/1 /boot ext3 defaults 0 0
/dev/md/2 / ext4 defaults 0 0
```

Why so many tempfs with allocating many 32Gb partitions?
Is this ok? or some miss configuration from the host?

I have 64Gb ram on this server and never requested any special tempfs partitions. I just got this as default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These `tmpfs` file systems are virtual, in-memory file systems that are needed by the system to run and reflect the standard Unix philosophy of "Everything is a file". They only occupy as much space in the RAM as they need. Don't worry about it.